# How do I check whether comma separated elements of a string are in the list or not?

Tags: python

```
a = "3"
b = ["3"]

def func():
    return a in b
```

The above function returns "TRUE"

But if I have my code as follows:

```
a="1,2,3,4"
b = ["3"]
```

How do I check the elements of a one by one with b, i.e, "1"==["3"] or "2"==["3"], and so on, and return "TRUE" when "3"==["3"]

Comment: Convert a to a list, then use in.

Comment: @nicomp If there is more than one item in the list, it might be better to use `set`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
a = "1,2,3,4"
b = ["3"]

def func(a, b):
    return any(e in b for e in a.split(','))


print(func(a, b))
```

Output

```
True
```

---

- Use [`split(',')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) for converting type `str` to `list`.
- Code inside the `any()` function `e in b for e in a.split(',')` returns a boolean list of `True` and `False` based on condition
- Here `e` values are `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`; for each, check if element `e` is in list `b`.
- Use the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function; it returns `True` if one of the conditions is true in the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_list_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.read()
    return contents.split(',')

def search_list(contents, value):
    if value in contents:
        return True
    else:
        return False
contents = get_list_from_file('test.csv')
value = input('Enter a value to search for: ')
if search_list(contents, value):
    print('Found')
else:
    print('Not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.Try this:

```
a="1,2,3,4"
b = ["3"]
a_list = a.split(',')
for i in a_list:
    if i in b:
        print("True")
        break
```

Output:

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python `.split()` method on `a` to create a new list that contains comma-delimited numbers:

```
new_list = a.split(',')
```

Now, you can use a for loop to go through `new_list` and check if any element equals `'b'`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the split method to convert string to array
2. Compare your value with the array.

   arr = "1,2,3,4"
   b = ["3"]

   def find():
   return b[0] in x

   x = arr.split(',')
   x = find()

   print(x)